# Using Spring Integration executorChannel with Spring Cloud Function

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-cloud-function

I'm using spring cloud function to process data from kafka with Flux. By default it processes data in the consumer thread (where message is consumed). I'm going to implement threadpool for paraller data processing and throttling and there is a great implementation in Spring Cloud Integration called executorChannel (https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/channel/ExecutorChannel.html)

Function implementation example:

```
public static class FN1 implements Function<Flux<String>, Flux<String>> {
  public Flux<String> apply(Flux<String> data) {
    return data
      .map(f ->  doSomething() )      
  }
}
```

So I found no simple way to connect functions implemented that way via executorChannel.

M.b. there is a way to define inputChannel type?

UPD: Read comments under Oleg's answer. They are very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleFunctoinAppApplication  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SampleFunctoinAppApplication.class, args);
        SubscribableChannel output = context.getBean("output", SubscribableChannel.class);
        output.subscribe(System.out::println);

        MessageChannel channel = context.getBean("executorChannel", MessageChannel.class);
        channel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("hello"));
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("executorChannel")
                .transform(echo())
                .channel("output")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExecutorChannel executorChannel() {
        return new ExecutorChannel(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    }

    public Function<String, String> echo() {
        return v -> v;
    }
}
```

What do you mean by "define inputChannel type"?

Comment: Yep, but one of the main of the SCF is that you can implement only a function or more and bind each other with external configuration using binders from swping cloud streams and function.definition

In you example this definitions is hardcoded.

Comment: "define inputChannel type" like this

```
@Bean
  @Transformer(inputChannel = "headerEnricherChannel", outputChannel = "transformChannel")
  public HeaderEnricher headerEnricher() {
    return new HeaderEnricher(Collections.singletonMap(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.SESSION_ID_HEADER,
        new ExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor<Object>("payload", null)));
  }
```

Comment: Then you're talking about spring-cloud-stream and functional bindings - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function, correct?

Comment: Ok.

1. I got several implemented functions Function<Flux<...>, Flux<...>>. 
2. I can use Spring Cloud Streams binders bind this functions to message brokers just configuring them. So implementation is simple as in can be. Everythin is great
3. I want to do throttling broker -> (direct channel) -> FN1 -> (executorChannel) -> FN2 

I want to keep flexibility of spring-cloud-functions and reuse already implementer executorChannel for throttling  cause it is great solution.

Just code everything -- ok, but m.b. there is more elegant solution?

Comment: You insist on having executorChannel without realising that consumer concurrency is already handled by the framework - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties. Please go through documentation. Also, it's not that you need the executor channel. That is just one of many implementation details. You have a business case which I assume requires concurrency, so consider stating your case so we can better advise you on he right path within spring portfolio.

Comment: I can't really confirm, but when I implemented simple http request inside Flux function (for example), independently of concurrency parameter, all requests where processed in one thread. Logs show that there were several consumer threads, but processing was singletreaded.

Comment: When you dealing with reactive functions it is different than imperative since reactive function only invoked once to connect and initiate the stream. The unit of processing in imperative function is single message while in reactive the entire stream. The reason why I am saying all that is because while reactive function gives you more power to handle complex use cases it also comes at the cost where certain responsibility falls on  the user including parralelization - `Flux.parallel()`

Comment: Oleg, thank you. So I knew about flux invocation specific, so that's I was thinking about executorChannel as a simple mechanics to organize throttling (move imperative code to threadpool). I'll try parallel for that.